# PHP Prepared Statements, how to shift data from one column to another

Tags: php, sql-update, prepared-statement

I'm trying to move the data from one column in my table, to another, and then setting the initial column back to zero. While the initial column is reset back to zero, it also adds that zero onto the end of target column (I'll provide some screenshots for context).

Here is my code:

```
function complete_da($da_id) {
        include 'connect.php';
        include 'globals.php';

        retrieve_user_data($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        nation_data_grab($_SESSION['logged_in']);
        echo "u_n_i: ".$user_nation_information['active_da']." <br>";

        $ret_da_info_sql = "SELECT `active_da`, `completed_da` FROM `nations` WHERE `nations`.`user_id` = ?;";
        $ret_da_info_stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($ret_da_info_stmt, $ret_da_info_sql)) {
            echo "Statement 1 Failed";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ret_da_info_stmt, "i", $user_data['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($ret_da_info_stmt);

            // Use get_result for *, bind_result for specific columns

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($ret_da_info_stmt, $active_da, $completed_da); 
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($ret_da_info_stmt);
            echo "u_n_i: ".$user_nation_information['active_da']." <br>";
            $updated_cda_str = ($completed_da .= ",".$active_da);
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($ret_da_info_stmt);

        $update_compl_with_active_sql = "UPDATE `nations` SET `completed_da` = ? WHERE `nations`.`user_id` = ?;";
        $update_compl_with_active_stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($update_compl_with_active_stmt, $update_compl_with_active_sql)) {
            echo "Statement 2 Failed";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_compl_with_active_stmt, "si", $updated_cda_str, $user_data['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($update_compl_with_active_stmt);

            $set_active_zero_sql = "UPDATE `nations` SET `active_da` = ? WHERE `nations`.`user_id` = ?;";
            $set_active_zero_stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);

            $zero = 0;

            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($set_active_zero_stmt, $set_active_zero_sql)) {
                echo "Statement 2 Failed";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($set_active_zero_stmt, "ii", $zero, $user_data['id']);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($set_active_zero_stmt);
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($set_active_zero_stmt);
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($update_compl_with_active_stmt);


        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```

Here is my table before the function is run:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtVm9.png)

Table after function has run:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA7VX.png)

When run, the debugging echos I used to check to see if the 'active_da' is set correctly produces this result (the 4 is the button ID, they are just triggers for the function for now):
[Results from echo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty2jh.png)

My question is, how can I just simply transfer the 'active_da' column onto the end of the 'completed_da' column without adding that extra zero?

EDIT: I believe this is the query that's throwing it off

```
$set_active_zero_sql = "UPDATE `nations` SET `active_da` = ? WHERE `nations`.`user_id` = ?;";
            $set_active_zero_stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);

            $zero = 0;

            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($set_active_zero_stmt, $set_active_zero_sql)) {
                echo "Statement 2 Failed";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($set_active_zero_stmt, "ii", $zero, $user_data['id']);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($set_active_zero_stmt);
            }
```

Comment: In the future, please don't include all the extra the 'noise' in your post and try and keep it concise, I have edited as such.

Comment: Okay will do, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: also if your question would just contain that single one query you actualy ask about, it would be just straight forward to answer. in it's current form it somehow provokes me to ask: and where didn't you find that not in the SQL book?

Comment: In the inital post I said that I've only been using the internet, I haven't got any books (which Script47 rightly edited out to make it more concise), I'm only learning as a hobby tbh.  Edit: also, I included the whole function in the event the error lies elsewhere, as I don't actually know where it's going wrong.

Comment: Creating a comma delimited list of keys or data is a Very bad idea. How are you going to use this data later. Take an hour and read a database design tutorial and learn how to create `link` tables instead

Comment: They're stored ID's for each action (a task basically), I explode them elsewhere to get the indiv ID's, I'll check out what you suggested though, I've only been doing this a couple months and always looking for better ways.

Comment: @JustCoNa: And can you highlight the database query that does not work in your favor?

Comment: I've edited the original question to include what I think is the problem, I could be wrong though.